# Jhipster customize the popup for create and edit

Tags: angular, popup, jhipster

I am training to customize popup for create and edit. However, I have relation between class, so when I want to add object A, it's necessary to put the field from the list of object B. For example, I have client have one or many contacts, so I need to post the fields of client with the name of contacts from list of contacts.

[create-service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5qXE.png)

[save-service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtuuD.png)

[popup-service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHcfv.png)

[html create and edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlg5p.png)

```
export class Client implements BaseEntity {
    constructor(
        public id?: string,
        public companyName?: string,
        public contacts?: Contact,
    ) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to edit them, so a good practice is to use DTO option and adapt your DTOs server-side to your view requirements. Also if you always edit your objects together you should consider not doing CRUD on both but only have one REST controller for both and work with DDD aggregates.

JHipster can only generate technical code because it has no business insights, it's up to you to adapt your REST API and views to your business requirements. exposing a REST controller per JPA entity is usually a first naive approach.

Comment: thanks, i resolve the problem but when i select the client field and the contact field
the save operation of the depending between this class dont saving in database , just the field client save.

   save() {
        this.isSaving = true;
        if (this.client.id !== null) {
            this.clientService.update(this.client).subscribe((response) =>
             this.onSaveSuccess(response), () => this.onSaveError());
        } else {
            this.clientService.create(this.client).subscribe((response) =>
             this.onSaveSuccess(response), () => this.onSaveError());

Comment: I don't understand your point. Comments are not the best way to share code and details, you should rather edit your question or create a new one if it's about a new problem